# postgreSQL how to select array query with multiple elements

Tags: sql, postgresql

i want to search product in array tags.

-table data-
`1 | Apple  | {red, fruit, morning}`
`2 | Banana | {yellow, fruit, meal}`
`3 | tomato | {red, vegetable, morning}`

-search keyword-
= red fruit

-result-
1 | Apple  | {red, fruit, morning}

I hope the results come out like that.
It is possible search for multiple keywords in a single query?

In the following way...?
`SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE any(tags) = {'red', 'fruit'}`

Comment: `SELECT * FROM _table WHERE ARRAY['red', 'fruit'] <@ tags;`